# Where to set session default value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

guys! 
Prior to asking i should mention, that i`m working without ActiveRecord or any self-hosted-database. So thats why i have to store some values in the session.

From the very begining i desided to set session value of the users city in the layout. - i supposed it would be loaded before anything else. So i`ve done something like this:

```
<% session[:city] ||= {:name => 'City-Name', :lat => '40', :lng => '40'}%>
```

But when i`m loading directly to inner page it occurs that session[:city is nil *(

How should i set the session properely, so that it wouldn`t be nil???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar needs in one of the applications I worked on. It needed the users data to be loaded on sign-in and stored in the session. So, wrote a module called session_helpers.rb with the following:

```
module SessionHelpers
  def get_value(key)
    session[key.to_sym]
  end

  protected
    def store_data(*objects)
      objects.each do |object|
        if object.is_a?(Hash)
          object.each do |key, value|
            session[key.to_sym] = value
          end
        end
      end
    end

    def remove_data(*objects)
      objects.each do |object|
        if object.is_a?(String)
          key = to_id(object)
        else
          key = to_id(object.class.name)
        end
        session[key] = nil
      end
    end

    def update_data(key, value)
      session[key.to_sym] = value
    end

  private
    def to_id(name)
      "#{name.parameterize('_').foreign_key}".to_sym
    end
end
```

You can make any or all the methods available to views as well:

```
# application_controller.rb
helper_method :get_value
```

From the model I would retrieve a hash of the data that needs to be put up in the session about the user:

```
def common_data
  @data = Hash.new

  @data.merge!( { 'news'         => self.news.count } )
  ...
  @data
end
```

As I wanted to do this after sign-in I overrode the devise method to do this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  store_data( '_count', current_user.common_data )

  dashboard_path
end
```

This way I was able to load important data about the user on sign-in and store it in the session and retrieve whenever I wanted. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, i just needed to set a session var for every newcomer whether he is logged in or not? does it work so?

Comment: Yup. It will, use store_data('varname', value)

Comment: so i should put store_data in my layout to check for setting a default value? instead of session[:key] ||=value ???

Comment: store_data is to put data into session. Come up with a before_filter in your application_controller to set the initial default values for the session. And, update those values when needed.

Comment: The answer is aimed at helping you come up with a neater API which is reusable at different situations. If you're not working with AR, then probably you would require to use more of session to store and retrieve values and this would help. Otherwise, if your requirement is  just to store and retrieve one / two values then this probably is a overkill. Make your choice.

Comment: THNX i finally  figured it out! `before_filter` is great. Now i`m studying your full example!